# SWIFT 2: Loop through JSON array

Tags: json, loops, swift2

I am getting this json from a url, the return JSON is:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Mary"},{"id":2,"name":"John"}]
```

I want to display the names in a TableView on IOS.

My Swift2 Code is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    var NumberOfPersons = 0

    var NameOfPerson = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        parseJSON()

    }

    func parseJSON(){

        do {

            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zzzzzz.com/API/name.php")!)

            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

            let NumberOfPersons = jsonResult.count

           **LOOP THROUGH THE JSON ARRAY**

        } catch let error as NSError {

            print(error)

        }
    }
}
```

How can I loop through the JSON array to put which name in a cell on a Table View?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The variable `jsonResult` is an array of dictionaries, so you can loop through the array with

```
for anItem in jsonResult as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] { // or [[String:AnyObject]]
  let personName = anItem["name"] as! String
  let personID = anItem["id"] as! Int
// do something with personName and personID
}
```

In **Swift 3** the unspecified JSON type has been changed to `Any`

```
for anItem in jsonResult as! [Dictionary<String, Any>] { ... // or [[String:Any]]
```

Answer (score 0):

make the JSON results in a DICT and get it with a loop "for (key, value)"

Comment: Do you mean: let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

If your is finally

```
let jsonResult = [{"id":1,"name":"Mary"},{"id":2,"name":"John"}]
var jsonDictResult[String: Int] = jsonResult;
```

**Updated:**

```
let jsonResult: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
    options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments,
    error:&parseError)
```

**Updated:**

Make the `JSON` results in a **DICT** and get it with a loop ***"for (key, value)"***

Comment: Thanky you. But can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: you make the array in a dict[key:value].
if your jsonResult is simply an array only.

Answer (score 0):

```
let jsonResult: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
  options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments,
  error:&parseError)
```