# i have simple json output and how to view result in table view swift language

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I have the following json output. How to parse json in swift so that I can display it in table view?

```
[{"firstName":"faisal","address":"Apartemen Casa Grande 0708"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code i hope help you**

```
  var parseError: NSError?
  let parsedObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
    options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments,
    error:&parseError)
 
  //2
  if let topApps = parsedObject as? NSArray 
  {
    if let feed = topApps["firstName"] as? NSDictionary 
    {
      if let feed = topApps["address"] as? NSDictionary 
      {
           println("Optional Binding: \(appName)")
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I will implement and test this code, thank you :)

Comment: if this code is work for you then Accept and upvote my answer @Faisal Thanks..

Comment: is this swift 1? Extra argument 'error' in call and i read about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073497/swift-extra-argument-error-in-call this show me a different code for Swift 2, can you help me solve this? thank you @Nikunj :)

Comment: this is swift 1.2 @Faisal

Comment: my requirement is swift 2 @Nikunj :D

Comment: thank you @Nikunj i just found the answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858531/swift-2-loop-through-json-array