# Loop through JSON response from Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, loops, swift2

I am using xcode 7.2 and swift 2.1.1. using Alamofire for server communication. I have a tableview that display's dynamic data.Data includes username , useremail , profilePicture etc. I Tried to implement  [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858531/swift-2-loop-through-json-array) code from stackoverflow. But I am getting a warning message says **Cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type '[Dictionary]' always fails** My json response is

```
{
  "JsonRequestBehavior" : 1,
  "MaxJsonLength" : null,
  "ContentType" : null,
  "Data" : {
    "_id" : "5658444778a7531f4c79c23d",
    "Photo" : "",
    "AllowSharing" : "YES",
    "MemberCount" : 5,
    "Users" : [
      {
        "_id" : "5658443478a7531f4c79c23c",
        "Photo" : "",
        "MembershipDate" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "MiddleName" : null,
        "FirstName" : "Gohan",
        "LastName" : null,
        "Email" : "gohan@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "_id" : "566ea5f1dfead62350cf0fad",
        "Photo" : "",
        "MembershipDate" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "MiddleName" : null,
        "FirstName" : null,
        "LastName" : null,
        "Email" : "sachin@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "MembershipDate" : "2015-12-14T12:03:12.819Z",
    "CreatedBy" : "5658443478a7531f4c79c23c"
  },
  "ContentEncoding" : null,
  "RecursionLimit" : null
}
```

How can I loop through **Users** in JSON response ?

**EDIT** as per JohnyKutty's answer I tried the same code in my Project. The code for the same is

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET,App.AppHomeURL() + "Load_Group", parameters: ["groupid":"\(groupId)"]).responseJSON
            {
                response in
                 print("\(response.data)")
                switch response.result
                {

                case .Success(let _data):
                    let jsonData = JSON(_data)
                    print("Admin Response : \(jsonData)")

                do
                   {
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(_data as! NSData, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                        if let DataObject = json["Data"] as? NSDictionary
                        {
                            if let users = DataObject["Users"] as? [NSDictionary]
                            {
                                for user in users
                                {
                                    print("User id : \(user["_id"])")
                                }
                            }
                        }

                   }

                    catch let error as NSError
                    {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
```

in this line   **let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(_data as! NSData, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary**
At first I used "_data" and then Xcode suggested a change and it changed from _data to _data as! NSData.

Comment: You can use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON).

Comment: Parse JSON data to custom objects, then any operation on them (e.g. iteration) will be easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your son structure is like following
JSON(Dictionary) -> Data(Dictionary) -> Users(Array of Dictionaries). So first you should pick the Users array from raw json then iterate through it.

Since alamofire is already serializing your response, No need to use JSONSerializer again, I am updating my answer.

**UPDATE**
Try this code inside the case

```
if let DataObject = _data["Data"] as? NSDictionary {
    if let Users = DataObject["Users"] as? [NSDictionary] {
        for user in Users {
            print(user["_id"],user["MembershipDate"],user["FirstName"],user["Email"], separator: "   ", terminator: "\n")
        }
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET,App.AppHomeURL() + "Load_Group", parameters: ["groupid":"\(groupId)"]) .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {

        case .Success(let _data):
            print(_data)
            if let DataObject = _data["Data"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let Users = DataObject["Users"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                    for user in Users {
                        print(user["_id"],user["MembershipDate"],user["FirstName"],user["Email"], separator: "   ", terminator: "\n")
                    }
                }
            }

        default:
            break;
        }


}
```

Comment: I tried your code but got an error . 
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(_data as! NSData, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary

Comment: This is the error ...   `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x109373ef0) to 'NSData' (0x109372e88).`

Comment: What you have tried? Can you update your question with your code?

Comment: it seems _data is already converted to JSON so, you can use like 'if let DataObject = _data["Data"] as? NSDictionary'.....

Comment: Yeah I have already changed the code the way you have updated. it's working ... !!!