# getting error while Parsing json Array in swift 3

Tags: json, parsing, swift3

I am trying to get an `JSON Array`, which is looks like this

```
[
  {
    "number": "111-1001"
  },
  {
    "number": "111-1002"
  },
  {
    "number": "111-1003"
  }
]
```

> For parsing this i write this code:

```
    let registeredNumberUrl = "http://myURL"
    let url = URL(string: registeredNumberUrl)
    do {


        let allregisteredNumber = try Data(contentsOf: url!)


        let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allregisteredNumber , options: []) as? [[String:Any]]

        print("jsonResult \(jsonResult?.count)")

    } catch let error as NSError{
        print(" !!!!  registered was not succeded  !!!! \(error)")

    }        
}
```

> But I'm getting this  error:

```
    Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
 Code=3840
 "No value for key in object around character 41." 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription= No value for key in object around character 41.
}
```

I have tried some solution like this
[SWIFT 2: Loop through JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858531/swift-2-loop-through-json-array)
 but I'm keep getting the same error:

Comment: The issue is related to the JSON rather than to the code. *This* JSON is valid. But if it *looks like*, it's not the actual JSON so how should we know? ...

Comment: The error's pretty clear: *"No value for key in object around character 41."* Look at the JSON and count the characters: There is no value for key `regNumbers`.

Comment: but when i am checking my link in Postman it gives me the right output of json.

Comment: Then maybe there are invalid characters which need to be escaped on the server-side.

Comment: Thanks @vadian it was the error from the server .